# Stress-energy tensor of electromagnetic wave in curved spacetime

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am trying to calculate the stress–energy tensor of an electromagnetic wave in curved spacetime, characterized by the diagonal metric
$$
g_{\mu\nu} =
\begin{pmatrix}
-g_{zz} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & g_{xx} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & g_{yy} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & g_{zz} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with signature (−, +, +, +), where $g_{xx},g_{yy},g_{zz}$ are arbitrary functions of the coordinates $t,x,y,z$ and $g_{tt}=-g_{zz}$. Assuming that the electric field $\vec{E}$ is oriented along the $x$-axis and the magnetic field $\vec{B}$ along the $y$-axis, the electromagnetic tensor becomes:
$$
F_{\mu\nu} =
\big|\vec{B}\big|
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations_in_curved_spacetime#Electromagnetic_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) and [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/478200/electromagnetic-stress-energy-tensor-in-curved-space-time), the stress–energy tensor is then given by:
$$
T_{\mu\nu} = -\frac{1}{\mu_0} \left( F_{\mu\alpha} g^{\alpha\beta} F_{\beta\nu} - \frac{1}{4} g_{\mu\nu} F_{\sigma\alpha} g^{\alpha\beta} F_{\beta\rho} g^{\rho\sigma} \right)
$$
Calculating the first term yields:
$$
F_{\mu\alpha} g^{\alpha\beta} F_{\beta\nu} = \big|\vec{B}\big|^2
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-g^{zz} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & g^{xx} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & g^{yy} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & g^{zz} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
F_{\mu\alpha} g^{\alpha\beta} F_{\beta\nu} = \frac{\big|\vec{B}\big|^2}{g_{xx}}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The term $F_{\sigma\alpha} g^{\alpha\beta} F_{\beta\rho} g^{\rho\sigma}$ is calculated by:
$$
\big|\vec{B}\big|^2\text{tr}\Bigg[\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-g^{zz} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & g^{xx} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & g^{yy} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & g^{zz} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-g^{zz} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & g^{xx} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & g^{yy} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & g^{zz} \\
\end{pmatrix}\Bigg]
$$
$$
F_{\sigma\alpha} g^{\alpha\beta} F_{\beta\rho} g^{\rho\sigma}
= \frac{\big|\vec{B}\big|^2}{g_{zz}g_{xx}}\text{tr}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
= 0
$$
Therefore the entire second term vanishes and the stress-energy tensor is only given by:
$$
T_{\mu\nu} = -\frac{\big|\vec{B}\big|^2}{\mu_0g_{xx}}\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
However, this seems wrong to me, since the stress-energy tensor is only dependent on the $g_{xx}$ component of the metric and not at all on the $g_{yy}$ component. Does that mean that the metric only has an effect on the electric field (in $x$-direction) and not on the magnetic field (in $y$-direction)? Or are there errors in my calculations? Perhaps the electromagnetic tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$ takes a different form in curved spacetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assumed that
$$
F_{\mu\nu} =
\big|\vec{B}\big|
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
you implicitly assumed that $g_{xx} = g_{yy} = 1$.  This is because the norm of a spacelike vector (such as $\vec{E}$ or $\vec{B}$), assuming a diagonal metric, is
$$
|\vec{B}|^2 = (B^x)^2g_{xx} + (B^y)^2g_{yy} + (B^z)^2g_{zz} = (B_x)^2g^{xx} + (B_y)^2g^{yy} + (B_z)^2g^{zz} \\ \neq (B^x)^2 + (B^y)^2 + (B^z)^2.
$$
The coordinate components of the tensor $F_{\mu \nu}$ are expressed in terms of the coordinate components $B_y$ and $E_x$; so if you want to express $F_{\mu \nu}$ in terms of the (spatially) invariant magnitude $|\vec{B}|$, you will have to include factors of the metric components as well.